# QGIS how to make options in valuemap invisible when outside constraint

Tags: qgis, database, forms

I am making a geopackage to plan aids to navigation in a maritime environment.

I have made the design of my attributes form with the drag/drop designer.
The constraints I put in work i.e. If i choose a lateral portside-hand mark i can not press o.k. unless the color red is chosen, although all the other colors are still visible in the valuemap i've set.

Is it possible to blank out the values in the valuemap when they fall outside of the limits of the constraints i've set? 
I would like to make the form idiot proof so the end-user can not choose an option that is outside the rules en regulations in the field.
[image]

Comment: I think the feature you want is called "drill down forms" or "cascading forms." There was a [crowd-funding request](https://north-road.com/drill-down-cascading-forms/) to implement it in QGIS, but I'm not sure if it succeeded.

Comment: The pull request was implemented (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/6982). Can you include the structure of the attributes tables or something to help reproduce and/or understand the desired behavior?